# R: loop to create a separate barplot for each factor level

Tags: r, loops, bar-chart, factors

I have learned how to arrange multiple plots :

```
windows(width=18,height=3) 
par(las=1,cex.lab=0.75,cex.axis=0.6, bty="n", mgp = c(1, 0.6, 0),oma = c(2,4,2,0) + 0.1, mar = c(4,0,3,3) + 0.1)
a=layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow = 1, ncol = 4,byrow=T))
layout.show(a)
```

And I know how to create a single plot which uses part of the data (one of the factor levels):

```
xmin=0
xmax=250
ymin=0
ymax=70
with(subset(df, Frequency=='6000'), barplot(value, beside=TRUE, col='black', ylim=c(ymin,ymax),xlim=c(xmin,xmax)))
rect(25,0,55,60, col= rgb(119,136,153, alpha=70, maxColorValue=225), border = "transparent")
axis(1, at=seq(0,250, by=50))
```

I am trying to learn how to efficiently add identical plots for different factor (Frequency) levels. I know I can select a different subset but that is very inefficient for many factor levels.

I tried something like this but it does not seem to work:

```
for ( i in 1:length(unique(df$Frequency)) ){
value <- subset( df, Frequency == unique ( df$Frequency )[i] )
barplot(value, main = paste0("Frequency: ",  unique(df$Frequency)) )
}
```

This is one of my first loops so any explanation would be very helpful...

My data:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tie9rrnmdxuua8c/df.csv?dl=0

```
df$Frequency = as.factor(df$Frequency)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone helped me with this question. The solution is below.

```
# space for plots

windows(width=18,height=3) 
par(las=1,cex.lab=0.75,cex.axis=0.6, bty="n", mgp = c(1, 0.6, 0),oma = c(2,4,2,0) + 
0.1, mar = c(4,0,3,3) + 0.1)
a=layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow = 1, ncol = 4,byrow=T))
layout.show(a)

# axes' limits

xmin=0
xmax=250
ymin=0
ymax=70

# loop

for ( i in 1:length(unique(df$Frequency)) ){

 value <- subset( df, Frequency == unique ( df$Frequency )[i] )

barplot(value$value, main = paste0("Frequency: ",  unique(df$Frequency)[i]),ylim=c(ymin,ymax),xlim=c(xmin,xmax) )
rect(25,0,75,70, col= rgb(119,136,153, alpha=70, maxColorValue=225), border = "transparent")
axis(1, at=seq(0,300, by=50))

}
```